# Transformations of stochastic matrix that preserve equilibrium

Tags: linear-algebra, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, hidden-markov-models

I have a stochastic (Markov) matrix $W$. I would like to modify it, such that $W_{i,i}$ increases for all $i$ (and thus other elements decrease). However, I don't want to change the equilibrium distribution of $W$, ie its leading eigenvector. Are there classes of transform that accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

For any $0 \leq t < 1$, the matrix $(1 - t)W + tI$ is a "lazier" version of your Markov chain that has the same equilibrium distribution.

Comment: Not exactly what I had in mind but that definitely works